# Fail to save/open documents to/from Desktop/Documents folder in Apple Apps

Tags: macos, icloud, finder, big-sur, mdm

Since upgrading to macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 we have one office where all Macs show the following problem:

- None of the Apple apps (Number, Pages, Mail, TextEdit etc.) can save or open files to or from the Desktop and Documents folder. First appears an error message "communication with a helper program failed"

[image]

- and afterwards one just sees a loading bar.

[image: loadingbar]

- Any other app can save/open files just fine (LibreOffice etc.)
- The Apple apps can still save to e. g. Downloads and open files from there
- In Finder I also cannot copy files to/from Desktop/Documents nor delete. However, in Terminal this works just fine.

I suspect some weird iCloud Drive issue in combination maybe with Apple's versioning? However, **none** of the machines have iCloud setup!

How can I solve this problem so that Numbers/Pages/Preview/Mail and other Apple Apps can read again form Desktop/Documents folder?

Any help is appreciated.

I tried to solve the issue by:

- completely reinstalling 11.5.2 but it didn't help.
- deleting Finder prefs and restarting Finder

**Update**

- admin users do not show the issue (only standard users)
- errors look like (at least that is all I could find)

```
<(null): 0x0> "<private>" Failed to coordinate for reading with error: errorClass=NSError, domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, code=4101 (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4101 UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600002044240 {Error Domain=NSFileProviderInternalErrorDomain Code=7 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002044540 {Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=4 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}}}}})

Will present error in document controller: errorClass=NSError, domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, code=4101 (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4101 UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600002044240 {Error Domain=NSFileProviderInternalErrorDomain Code=7 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002044540 {Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=4 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}}}}})

Error synchronizing with cloud for <SYDClientToDaemonConnection: 0x60000021d2c0; storeConfiguration=<SYDStoreConfiguration: 0x600003f1b860; storeID=<SYDStoreID: 0x600003d3f680; identifier=com.apple.iWork type=1>>>: Error Domain=SyncedDefaults Code=1234 "Failed to sync with CloudKit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to sync with CloudKit}

<(null): 0x0> "<private>" Failed to coordinate for reading with error: errorClass=NSError, domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, code=4101 (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4101 UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000336ced0 {Error Domain=NSFileProviderInternalErrorDomain Code=7 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000336d890 {Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=4 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}}}}})
```

### UPDATE

The issue is caused by this mobile config. However, I can see nothing wrong with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Screensaver</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.screensaver.B2EF0D8A-FC65-4BE8-8773-A702CF28A6D3</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.screensaver</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>DC8B2BA0-1E7A-413B-ACBF-F6943371982E</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>askForPassword</key>
            <true/>
            <key>askForPasswordDelay</key>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <key>idleTime</key>
            <integer>900</integer>
            <key>moduleName</key>
            <string>Flurry</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>DisableSoftwareUpdateNotifications</key>
            <true/>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>App Store settings</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.appstore.75AD1E4F-F25E-4811-A1F8-7C10DA0776E6</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.appstore</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>9A6BCA65-8A28-4AF9-9FE7-4CCC40701549</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>restrict-store-mdm-install-softwareupdate-only</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>AppleShowAllExtensions</key>
            <true/>
            <key>AppleShowScrollBars</key>
            <string>Always</string>
            <key>CSUIDisable32BitWarning</key>
            <true/>
            <key>MultipleSessionEnabled</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Global Preferences</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>.GlobalPreferences.EEB25794-1672-432A-81B4-6DB1EAFE4A7B</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>.GlobalPreferences</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>9FE44505-3DE3-4B12-8B6E-5B7B6B1E8080</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>com.apple.autologout.AutoLogOutDelay</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>New to Mac</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.touristd.C50AF5A4-47BB-4607-8BDC-3A4ED2314ABE</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.touristd</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>37807F38-E8BF-4513-89AC-737758D45B1B</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>DoNotOfferNewDisksForBackup</key>
            <true/>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Time Machine</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.TimeMachine.1E8D5A0C-38EF-495D-BCB8-E9A0099CBDDC</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.TimeMachine</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>AE797016-BC70-40DB-A46B-5AC2A2FEF205</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Numbers #1</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.iWork.Numbers.8756CCC0-F68C-4C9A-81E8-D219A6570FCF</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.iWork.Numbers</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>769F4464-3787-49BA-9E96-9AB6A80FE4C1</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>TMAFirstLaunchVersion</key>
            <integer>99</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Pages #1</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.iWork.Pages.2884A71F-B2D8-48FB-B4BC-526F13E02EB9</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.iWork.Pages</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>1AAF523A-4E68-4E7B-91D6-7D8AD4F8743E</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>TMAFirstLaunchVersion</key>
            <integer>99</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>OnboardingUserViewedWelcomeSlide</key>
            <true/>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>The Unarchiver (Mac App Store)</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>cx.c3.theunarchiver.2A03B27C-51B9-4455-99FF-B446D583A779</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>cx.c3.theunarchiver</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>2B602C9F-1E7C-47C5-9BD3-EFDFD36C44C2</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Keynote #1</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.iWork.Keynote.8F30855A-E7AB-47B6-9EE8-26124BA0DE08</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.iWork.Keynote</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>16F6CED8-257E-45B8-B836-DDD1D60616B1</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>TMAFirstLaunchVersion</key>
            <integer>99</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>GarageBand</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.garageband10.E2FEFE1F-F552-43A8-8000-42F1DA134449</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.garageband10</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>E3B314C7-958F-43BC-B330-EAFFB7D1CA0E</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>RecentWhatsNewPanelVersion</key>
            <integer>99</integer>
            <key>welcomeScreenShown</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>iMovie</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.iMovieApp.A03CA638-E926-4082-BBD8-9B18F26EB07E</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.iMovieApp</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>8F86AF00-548F-459D-8053-8DF9755E1BB7</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>DisableDeviceBackups</key>
            <true/>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>iTunes #1</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.iTunes.04A268F8-53E9-449A-ADB0-C1EC2166DE32</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.iTunes</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>4BC7DEB9-8D00-4A12-A935-57B418C97A21</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>disableCheckForUpdates</key>
            <true/>
            <key>disableShareLibraryInfo</key>
            <true/>
            <key>disableSharedMusic</key>
            <true/>
            <key>dontAutomaticallySyncIPods</key>
            <true/>
            <key>license-agreements</key>
            <dict>
                <key>EA1510</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>restrictGames</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>General</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>1234567890</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>Some Company</string>
    <key>PayloadScope</key>
    <string>System</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>56230443-0C3E-46B8-919E-C98F05532F20</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>TargetDeviceType</key>
    <integer>5</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: "We have one location" Can you describe what is particular to this setup? Are the Macs managed by any software? Are No AppleIDs used on these Macs? My first thought is that it's a TCC issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @benwiggy I updated my description. The Macs are managed by an MDM, Mosyle to be precise.